# Struts2 tree tag with checkbox

Tags: struts2, treeview

I Am Trying to build a form having a tree where each node in the tree needs to have a check box to take input from the user.

How can I accomplish this using struts2 tree tag? .can any one please help me.

Comment: have you look at http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action.

Comment: But it is only design view for tree view.basically I am a beginner in cause of struts2.can you please provide the Action class for this.

Comment: download the plugin from here http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/TreeTag

Comment: It is only .jar file for jquery plug-in. can You please provide location of whole .zip file for this application.

Comment: that is S2 plugin for Jquery so all you need to add that jar file to the class path and use its tag library

Comment: OK Thank You..I am adding .jar and create a jsp with that codes.but the output is only displaying three submit button.There is no tree view.can you please specifies the order of this application which am follow.

Comment: have you followed this example http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/TreeTag and if it snot working show the code which you have done so far

Comment: can you please check this lik:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525318/iterate-list-of-objects-using-struts2-iterator